# is there a way to create filename for urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob)

Tags: javascript

I'm not that familiar with Javascript, is there a way that I can create my own filename? What happens is it opens a new tab and the filename is in Guid Format.

```
if (urlCreator && headers['content-type'] != 'application/octet-stream') {
  // Fallback to $window.location method
  try {
    // Prepare a blob URL
    // Use application/octet-stream when using $window.location to force download
    var objectUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
    $window.open(objectUrl);
    success = true;
  } catch (ex) {
    //console.log("Download link method with $window.location failed with the following exception:");
    //console.log(ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to stay on the user's side. Then the only option I know, in supporting browsers, is to use an anchor element (`<a>`) and set its `download` attribute to the filename you want, and its `href` to the objectURL you got. But then you won't be able to use `window.open()` If you wanted to save the file on server, you could have used a `FormData` object to send the blob (not the objectURL!) and set the 3rd parameter of `FormData.append()` to your wanted filename.

Comment: thank you for replying @Kaiido, Ill research on it :)

Comment: @Kaiido, last, I wasn't planning to save it, more of retrieval. The data already came from the backend, I just want to view it on the browser with the filename :)

Comment: you want like the title of the new window be e.g *"yourFile.png (PNG Image....)"* ? In Firefox, you can first convert your Blob to a File using `new File(blob, fileName)` but it doesn't seem to work in Chrome. So the best cross-browser solution might be `var win = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob)); win.onload = function(){ this.document.title = 'someFile.xxx';};`. Note that none of the above method will set the file's name when you right-click, save-as the image (if we're talking about images)

Comment: @Kaiido, thank you, this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) for this:

```
var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```